# curl php url works fine local, not responding on server

Tags: php, curl

I've made a little curl script, works as expected while running it in localhost, but I keep getting connection timed-out when I run this on my server...

The endpoint_token = https://ngf.rhm.cloud:8244/token.

```
$curl = curl_init($this->endpoint_token);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER,'Content-Type: application/json');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        $postData = "";

        foreach($this->params as $k => $v)
        {
            $postData .= $k . '='.urlencode($v).'&';
        }

        $postData = rtrim($postData, '&');

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);


        $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
```

Why is it functioning as expected localhost, but doing nothing on my server?

Comment: is your server allowed to make outgoing http connections? or is your server allowed to connect to the endpoint_token url?

Comment: @MarcB Is there an easy/quick way to check this?

Comment: fire up curl connections to any other site. if those work, but not your url, then youserver is blocked somehow. if no other sites work, then try some other app. e.g. open a shell and try to telnet to port 80 somewhere, or use command line curl/wget. maybe the webserver process is firewalled from opening outgoing connections, blah blah blah. If nothing works at all, then all outgoing connection requests are blocked.

Comment: I can use curl for another other site, only having problem (that I know of) with this specific url/port. Can the problem be related to the port?

Comment: Did some testing, seems that the server I'm working on is blocking url's that have don't have a valid https certificate. If you go to https://193.239.132.232:8245 you'll get a certificate warning. 
That's the IP resolved from the domain ngf.rhm.cloud.

Comment: you can't test certs until AFTER a connection is established.

Comment: Hmm, I see. Did some testing on my own server, using the exact same scripts and they work fine. So I guess either the customers server is blocking something or the endpoint location is not answering the calls from that specific server, which they told me is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Check for errors and display the error message
if($errno = curl_errno($curl)) {
    $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
    echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}";
}
```

try to see for errors